# Docker compose wait for database service initialisation

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a spring boot project which I'd like to containerize using docker.
I have a couple of spring boot applications which connect to same MySql server.

My spring applications requires the database to be completely setup (i.e. all the tables to be created and some data to be inserted in some of the tables) in order to start.

I am using **Docker** version **18.09.0** and **docker-compose** version **1.23.1** and ubuntu **16.04** LTS

---

I have two files **`create.sql`** and **`insert.sql`**, which I use to initialise the database to be used by the application.

I create the images using the command **`docker-compose.yml`** and it runs successfully and creates the images.

I have the following questions.

1. I assume when using docker-compose, a container starts as soon as all its dependent containers have started. Is there a way to wait for the mysql server to be up and ready to accept connections, before my API container gets started?
2. If I chose to create containers separately for the applications and mysql, and not use docker-compose, how do I make sure that my applications connect to the mysql container?
3. Is there any other tool which might help me achieve this?

**Note:**
I have tried to use **`docker inspect <container_id>`** to find the the IpAddress for the mysql container and use it to connect, but it doesn't work as well.

---

The following are the files I am using to create images.

**`docker-compose.yml`** file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  demo-mysql:
    image: demo-mysql
    build: ./demo-mysql
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=demo
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root

  demo-api:
    image: demo-api-1.0
    build: ./api
    depends_on:
      - demo-mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=demo-mysql
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_NAME=demo
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306

  demo1-app:
    image: demo1-app-1.0
    build: ./demo1
    depends_on:
      - demo-mysql
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=demo-mysql
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_NAME=demo
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

The following is the **`Dockerfile`** for the spring boot project

```
FROM java:8

VOLUME /tmp

ARG DATA_PATH=/src/main/resources
ARG APP_PORT=8080

EXPOSE ${APP_PORT}

ADD /build/libs/demo-api.jar demo-api.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo-api.jar"]
```

The following is the **`Dockerfile`** I used to create my mysql image

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=demo \
    MYSQL_USER=root \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

ADD ./1.0/create.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ADD ./1.0/insert.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `healthcheck` feature of docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck). 
Something like this:

```
services:
  demo-mysql:
    image: demo-mysql
    build: ./demo-mysql
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=demo
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'mysqladmin ping']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10
```

The depending containers will not start until the demo-mysql container is healthy

Comment: @greenPadawan: you are right, need to use "mysqladmin ping" for the healthcheck.

Comment: health checks are no longer helping, condition on depends_on has been removed in docker 3, so even if you add your spring boot application to depend on the database, it will wait for it to run, not be ready.

Comment: @GeorgeMarin: right, the current supported way: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Please update the answer as this is no longer working. See the comment above.

Comment: Hello, i can recommend you to use `/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=root --execute "SHOW DATABASE;"` in healthcheck script instead of `mysqladmin ping`. This wait for real initialization.

Comment: @Skraloupak: it's SHOW DATABASE**S** and had to use "CMD" instead of "CMD-SHELL" to make it work but although I see the health check succeeds it doesn't seem to make docker wait for mysql to be healthy before it starts further containers

Comment: In current docker versions you must specifiy 'condition: service_healthy' in order for that to work. See my complete answer.

Comment: @Skraloupak: I must make a correction: SHOW DATABASE didn't work for me either, I ended up with the jwilder/dockerize method mentioned by Ewaren

Answer (score 1):

In the current Docker version 24, `depends_on` by default only waits until the container it depends on is started, which ignores the health check. If you need to wait for it to become "healthy", you need to use the long syntax and specify the `condition` as `service_healthy` or in my case when using jwilder/dockerize `service_completed_successfully`.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-1

```
services:
   mysql:      
      image: mysql:8.0.34
     environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
        MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
     ports:
        - 3306:3306      
     healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/mysql", "--user=root",  "--password=mypassword", "--execute", "SHOW DATABASES;"]
     interval: 2s
     timeout: 2s
     retries: 10

   check-db-started:
      image: jwilder/dockerize:0.6.1          
      depends_on:
         - mysql          
      command: 'dockerize -wait=tcp://mysql:3306 -timeout 30s'

   springbootapp:
      image: myappimage
      environment:
         MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      ports:
         - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
         check-db-started:
            condition: service_completed_successfully
```